# Sql query selecting from both tables.

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a query which looks like this 
`$db->query("SELECT A.page_id, A.page_name FROM user_likes_pages as A , user_likes as B WHERE A.page_id = B.page_id AND B.country_id = ".$user_reg."  ");`
The thing is, I want to select a column from `user_likes`. Do I have to make a join or I can do it in different way. Thank you.

Comment: Have you tried `B.Column_Name` in your select query ?

Comment: what column do you want to select ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a `join` in your query, but it is implicit.  You should write the query as:

```
SELECT ulp.page_id, ulp.page_name, ul.<whatever>
FROM user_likes ul JOIN
     user_likes_pages ulp
     ON ul.page_id = ulp.page_id 
WHERE ul.country_id = ".$user_reg."
```

In addition to adding the explicit `join` syntax, I also changed the table aliases so they are abbreviations of the table name.  This makes it easier to read the query and avoid mistakes.

Answer (score 1):

You select B.columnname. You don't need a join, because you have the A.page_id = B.page_id.